Ajax calls parallel instead of serial (but not when called from localhost)
I'm running a WCF Service on IIS. The Service uses "webHttpBinding" and
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>

Then I'm doing some ajax calls from my webapp.

request witch takes really long
multiple short calls every 1s for status updates

Im running my app on http://localhost and everything works just fine. But when I'm running my app on the server on https://dev.server.com the requests are sent to the server but they have to wait until the first very long request is done. So this leads to very long "waiting for server response" times in the short requests.
How could this be? I mean it's the same service and same requests - why is localhost parallel and from the dev-server its serial?

I think it has something to do with your remote server configuration. When you're running on localhost, there may not be much limit to the reuse of connections. On a remote server that uses HTTPS, especially when HTTP/2 is enabled, the server may throttle concurrent connections. This results in multiple short requests waiting for the first request to be processed.

Not only that, but also your server must have a different basic setup than the local localhost. The local localhost connects to the local service, and many security issues are skipped, and even the remote server has a special firewall. Therefore, I suggest that you review the server settings and service configuration before further optimization.

Just to be clear, I'm doing the requests to same server (not localhost). Just my app is running on localhost vs. on server. I think you are right with your first comment, but what do I need to configure? I checked all settings and limits and nothing helps...
